# how to apply a custom function to a specific field in a number of queries in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple model

```
class Person(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
```

when I do `Person.objects.all()` I get Queryset with 20 results

I want to apply a custom function

```
def foo(name):
    return "Hello" + str(name)
```

I don't want to use any loops
is there any better method so that when I query I directly get these values

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Sorry for complaining, but formatting your code improves readability a lot and will in general help you get more support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run all kind of functions on the DB directly. Django provides an API for that though Database Functions.

Here is how to archive your example. For that we will use the Concat function, which allows us to concatenate strings. We also need the Value function, which allows us to provide Python variables directly to the DB. Finally, we are using `annotate` to add a calculated field to a queryset.

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Person.objects.annotate(name_plus=Concat(Value("Hello"), "name"))
```